# $\Bbb R^n \times (0,\infty)$ what does this mean?

Tags: real-numbers

Just began to read about PDEs. There are a whole list of notations which I don't understand and the book isn't expecting a reader who is as inexperienced as me.

Also don't understand what this means:
$U_T = U \times (0,T]$

I know the bit in the back is about a range.  But why is there a multiplication sign in the middle?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means a [Cartesian product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CartesianProduct.html). Note that since it is a "product", it is natural to have "power". $\Bbb R^n = \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \times \dots \times \Bbb R$ for $n$ times.

$U_T$ is probably a notation of the author.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Now the equation makes perfect sense to me.  The $U_T$ is taken from Appendix A.2 Geomatric Notations from Lawrence Evans's book on PDE.  Could this mean that it is differentiable T times? Purely guessing...

Comment: @PDElearner The usual notation for $n$th derivative is a superscript (with parentheses to prevent confusion with power), and notation for a function $f$ being differentiable for $n$ times is $f \in C^n$. (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness)) $U_T$ you mentioned just looks like the domain of pde, but $u_t$ can mean the partial derivative of $u$. You'd better read context for definition of these notations. BTW if you think this answer is the most helpful, please hit the "click" button on the left hard! :)

Comment: I mean "tick" button

Answer (score 2):

In general $A\times B$ for sets is the set of pairs $(a, b)$, where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.